# How do I use jquery within the serverless framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I would like to make use of the jquery deferred method in my serverless lambda project. However after requiring both jquery & jquery-ui as dependencies, the following error occurs when I attempt to make use of the jquery library? I'm new to serverless and lambda so please see the handler.js function below.

```
TypeError: $.each is not a function
at /vagrant/project/node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js:690:3
at widgetUuid (/vagrant/project/node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js:24:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/project/node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js:26:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/project/handler.js:4:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocalNodeJs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:156:33)
at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocal (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:114:19)
at AwsInvokeLocal.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
```

handler.js

```
'use strict';

global.jQuery = require('jquery');
global.jQueryUI = require('jquery-ui');

var Model = require('./resources/model');

module.exports.project =  function(event, context, callback) {
    Model.init();
};
```

model.js

```
var JsonFile = require('jsonfile');
var $ = global.jQueryUI;

module.exports = {
    init : function() {
        var self = this;

        self.fetch_file().done(function(file){
             console.log(file);
        });
    },

    fetch_file : function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        JsonFile.readFile('path to file', function (err, file) {
            deferred.resolve(file);
        });

        return $.when(deferred).promise();
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "avro-js": "^1.8.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.88.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jsonfile": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

After requiring Jquery instead of JqueryUI I get this exception:

```
    TypeError: $.Deferred is not a function
    at Object.fetch_schema (/vagrant/project/resources/model.js:17:26)
    at Object.init (/vagrant/project/resources/model.js:11:14)
    at module.exports.pixel_event_lambda_producer (/vagrant/project/handler.js:9:10)
    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocalNodeJs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:229:12)
    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocal (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:114:19)
From previous event:
    at Object.invoke:local:invoke [as hook] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:24:10)
    at BbPromise.reduce (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:218:55)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:218:22)
    at PluginManager.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:237:17)
    at variables.populateService.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:99:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:86:74)
    at serverless.init.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:39:50)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: `var $ = global.jQueryUI;` -> `var $ = global.jQuery;`

Comment: I tried using JQuery but got the error: $.Deferred is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved when I specifically required the jquery-deferred module which can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-deferred

Answer (score 1):

You have confused jQuery with jQuery UI. In your model.js, replace:

```
var $ = global.jQueryUI;
```

With:

```
var $ = global.jQuery;
```

[Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) is a jQuery method, and not a jQuery UI feature.

Comment: I tried using JQuery but got the error: $.Deferred is not a function

Comment: Look the zip folder inside the `.serverless` folder. Do you see the jQuery module there?

Comment: Yes I can see the jquery module in the node_modules directory of the zip folder inside . serverless

Comment: I have added the exception ^.

Comment: If you run this file locally, does it work? Try running it directly with `node handler`. Also. try again without using the `global` and replace it with `require('jquery')`.

Comment: yeah I tried both of these ^ still get the same error: $.Deferred is not a function